# Как на C++ оценить скорость выполнения участка кода?

Tags: c++, профилирование

Используя clock и вычитивая количество тиков я всегда получаю разное количество тиков. Как и Можно ли узнать скорость выполнения участка кода при не изменяющейся параметрах работы процессора и т.д? Т.е чтобы при таком-то коде - столько-то тиков, добавляю операцию - немного больше тиков, убираю ее и столько же тиков сколько в начале

Comment: Используйте профайлер или google bench и не забудьте прогонять интересующее место многократно.

Comment: Обычно для этого делается 1. цикл с большим количеством повторений, 2. много экспериментов с усреднением, и обычно 3. таймер с высоким разрешением. Но это все эксперимент - в котором без усреднения и оценки разброса не обойтись...

Answer (score 0):

Как выше заметили, всё равно будет требоваться многократный прогон, и усреднение значений. Как таковой волшебной палочки -- нету, подобие -- профайлеры.

Как вариант использовать отдельный пк, с начисто установленной системой и вашим ПО, отключить функции энергосбережения и систем защиты. Так вы сможете минимально нивелировать внешние факторы , и таймер будет показывать более точные значения